# Unix sed command in Dockerfile

Tags: unix, sed, dockerfile

Example found on GitHub:

```
FROM "xxx"/nginx-php-fpm:php73

MAINTAINER "xxx"

# Remove existing webroot, configure PHP session handler for Redis, install postgresql-client (pg_dump)
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/* && \
sed -i -e "s/memory_limit\s*=\s*.*/memory_limit = 256M/g" ${php_conf} && \
...
```

As I have understood the meaning of OPTIONS:
`-i`: "where to edit" and
`-e`: "script to be executed"

My question is:  What does this line do?
 `sed -i -e "s/memory_limit\s*=\s*.*/memory_limit = 256M/g" ${php_conf}`

When I try to run the line the response is: `sed: no input files`
How does it understand the `${php_conf}`?

Comment: Clearly it doesn't, probably because you have not defined this variable.

Comment: https://github.com/wyveo/craftcms-docker/blob/craft3/Dockerfile is rather inefficient; somebody should tell the maintainer [how to combine multiple `sed` commands in one script.](/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/wyveo/nginx-php-fpm/blob/master/Dockerfile#L8 seems to be where the variable gets defined.  This too has the same antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

That line is replacing all the matches `memory_limit = ...` to `memory_limit = 256M` in the `php_conf` file.
The problem in that Dockerfile is that you have not defined the environment variable `php_conf` and therefore there's no input file.

You could easily fix that by adding the env variable before your RUN command:

```
ENV php_conf /path/to/your/php_config
```